# Prove that $\lfloor x \rfloor +\lfloor 2x \rfloor + \dots +\lfloor 32x \rfloor =12345$ has no solution

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

Given that $\lfloor x \rfloor  +\lfloor 2x \rfloor + \dots +\lfloor 32x \rfloor  =12345$
where $\lfloor x \rfloor $ denotes the floor function,
prove that there is no $x$ that satisfies the equation.

Comment: It's not clear whatever it's $\sum_{k=1}^{32} [kx]$ or $\sum_{k=0}^5 [2^kx]$. Can you clear that up please?

Comment: In other words, you've used ". . ." here in a particularly ambiguous way.  Probably you would have written everything out if you meant:  $$\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor 2x \rfloor + \lfloor 4x \rfloor + \lfloor 8x \rfloor + \lfloor 16x \rfloor + \lfloor 32x \rfloor = 12345 $$ but it's worth saying it precisely, one way or the other.

Answer (score 2):

It is not true.  Write $y=\lfloor x \rfloor$ and let $z=x-y$ be the fractional part of $x$.  Your equation becomes $$528 y +\sum_{i=1}^{32} \lfloor iz \rfloor =12345$$
As $z \lt 1$ the sum is less than $528$ so $y=23$ and the equation becomes 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{32} \lfloor iz \rfloor =201$$
and $z=0.41, x=23.41$ works perfectly.  I just added it up in a spreadsheet and did a hand binary search to find which terms increase to bring the sum up to $12345$ and $12346$.  Any $x \in [\frac {515}{22},\frac {398}{17})\approx [23.40909,23.41176)$ works.
[image]

Comment: what about summing on the $\lfloor 2^iz \rfloor$ ?

Comment: He is looking for an integer solution, not a decimal fraction.

Comment: @GabrielRomon:  I find that reading of the question perverse, but the same approach works.  There is no solution.  $x=195.99$ gives a sum of $12342$ and $x=196$ gives $12348$ because all the terms hit an integer at once and the sum increments by $6$.

Comment: @poetasis:  No.  If $x$ is an integer all those floor signs do not matter.  We are clearly looking for real $x$ that satisfies the equation.  The point is to choose the fractional part so the floor gives the correct sum.

Comment: @Ross Millikan : Using the floor function for x will result in integers all the way. OTOH, If done for odds and evens separately, the evens will yield the next higher integer than the odds.  I will edit my answer

Comment: @poetasis:  the equation applies the floor to each product separately, then adds the results.  It is not so simple as the evens yielding the next higher integer than the odds.  As the fractional part goes through $1/2$ all the even terms increment by $1$.  As it goes through $7/17$ the $\lfloor 17x \rfloor$ term increments by $1$.  In this case that is the increment that takes away from $12345$

Comment: @Ross Millikan; Check out 23.769 in my updated answer. My math didn't find it but a manual binary search did.

Comment: @poetasis:  For $x=23.769$ I get a sum of $12553$.  You can't assume that only the evens carry.  Just do the sum in a spreadsheet using the built in floor function and you will see the values I give are correct.  I also give an Alpha link that shows it.

Comment: In my spreadsheet using x=23.769,, the sum of integer parts of 1x+3x...31x added to 5888. The sum of integer parts of 2x+4x+...32x added to 6457. Together they added up to 12345.

Comment: Forgive me, I copied the wrong number. Try 23.41.

Comment: Yes, that works, as my answer has said all along.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\lfloor x \rfloor  +\lfloor 2x \rfloor + \lfloor 4x \rfloor +\lfloor 8x \rfloor +\lfloor 16x \rfloor+\lfloor 32x \rfloor \leq 63x < \lfloor x \rfloor  +\lfloor 2x \rfloor + \lfloor 4x \rfloor +\lfloor 8x \rfloor +\lfloor 16x \rfloor+\lfloor 32x \rfloor+6\\
12345 \leq 63 x < 12351 \\
196-\frac{1}{21} \leq x < 196+\frac{1}{21}\\
196-\frac{2}{32} < x < 196+\frac{2}{32}\\$$

Now, split the problem in the following cases:

- $x \in (196-\frac{2}{32}, 196-\frac{1}{32})$
- $x \in [196-\frac{1}{32}, 196)$
- $x \in [196, 196+\frac{1}{32})$
- $x \in [196+\frac{1}{32}, 196+\frac{2}{32})$